# Unable to login in to SQL Server for all the users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, admin, database-administration

Suddenly I am unable to login to our SQL Server. No one in the office is able to connect to the server. What could be the issue?

Error

> Login Failed for user XXX/YYY (Microsoft SQL Server, Error; 18456)

Comment: Are you trying to log in remotely or from a computer on the same domain, or from the actual server housing the SQL Server database?

Comment: i have tried logging in directly into server and also SSMS from my Client system

Comment: More information is needed.  What credentials are you using (SQL or Windows)?  How is the login window appearing for you (Mixed Mode or SQL)?  Is this on a domain?  Are you logging in with the right domain credentials?  [More troubleshooting here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/40d83498-f52f-41e9-8d11-f2ea43413479/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456in-windows-2008?forum=sqlgetstarted)

Comment: Close SSMS , Right click SSMS , Run As Administrator and use Window authentication.

Comment: Yes i tried with both Sql and Windows.Its mixed mode.yes this is in domain..even my team members are unable to login.

Comment: @M.Ali    Hi ali even i tried that its still showing the above error

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the following:

1. Check if the SQL Server / SQL Server Agent Services in the Services.msc are not stopped. If they are start them and try connecting.
2. Sometimes it also can be that your account is disabled. You could try creating another Windows user, adding it to the local administrator group on your computer, log onto your computer with that account and try accessing SQL Server then.

When i had similar issue(s) the above solutions worked.

Happy coding.

Comment: I have logged in with admin credentials and found some of the user logins including me got deleted...I have created those user accounts and after some the same time user logins got deleted again.what might be the reason

Comment: It is tough to comment on what might have actually happened. I might need some more information. However, i believe you have figured out the core issue now?

Comment: Ya i have added the users who got logged out with sqladmin,but after some time same set of user accounts got deleted again.I am still unable to find the reason